# Documentation or reference for "NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1" DOCTYPE

Tags: browser, bookmarks, netscape

Is there any standard (possibly created after-the-fact) that governs `<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>` files? If you export bookmarks from either Chrome or Firefox (tried on Windows 10) you get this kind of file, which seems to be HTML of sorts.

I've tried [searching the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22DOCTYPE+NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1%22+standard) but found only pragmatic results like parsers in specific programming stacks, or tips and tricks on importing and exporting it.

Is there any standard, RFC, format description, or reference parser, or something similar?

Answer (score 8):

Not even valid HTML it is, neither technically, nor semantically. And it seems that modern browsers interpret the factual standard loosely when writing such files, but luckily also when importing.

The best available format description (probably reverse engineered, yes) seems to be this one:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753582(v=vs.85)

And it's by Microsoft of all things...